# Adding GPX vector layer not loading all link elements in file

Tags: qgis, gpx

I am loading a GPX file into QGIS 2.18 and all seems to work ok. I am finding that the attributes table is only showing me the first two link_href entries. I have some points and tracks in my GPX file that have more than 2 link entries and these seem to be getting dropped on import.

Is there a way to extend the capabilities of the GPX import to load up more of the link entries in my GPX files? Adding 3 more to allow up to 5 links should be all that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it...

All that was needed was to add the GPX_N_MAX_LINKS environment variable to my system and set this to the number of links I was looking to have visible. Setting this to 5 did the trick for me.